# Observable pipe async usually empty until multiple refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

The condition `observable$ | async; else loading; let x` most of the time stops in loading and it takes only some refreshes in the browser for the data to appear.

Here is the code I used:

```
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

course: Course;

sessions: Session[] = [];
sessionssubject$ = new Subject();
sessions$ = this.sessionssubject$.asObservable();

tasks: Task[] = [];
taskssubject$ = new Subject();
tasks$ = this.taskssubject$.asObservable();

constructor(
    protected courseService: CoursesService,
    protected taskService: TasksService,
    protected sessionService: SessionsService) { }


ngOnInit() 
{
        
    this.courseService.get(id).subscribe(
           data =>{
                this.course = data;
                this.sessionService.getByCourseId(this.course.id).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        data.sort((a, b) => a.startDate < b.startDate ? -1 : 1);
                        this.sessions = data;
                        this.sessionssubject$.next(this.sessions)
                    }   
                );
                this.taskService.getByCourseId(this.course.id).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.tasks = data;
                        this.taskssubject$.next(this.tasks);
                    }
                );
            }
      );
}
```

And here is part of `HTML` file used:

```
<nb-card class="left-margin-10">
        <nb-card-header>
            Sessions
            <button *ngIf="user.id == courseOwner.id" button nbButton status="success" class="float-right" (click)="open_session_modal(sessionDialog)">Add session</button>
        </nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-body>
            <ng-container *ngIf="sessions$ | async; let sss">
            <div *ngIf="sessions.length > 0; else nosession">
                <nb-card *ngFor="let session of sss">
                    <nb-card-body>
                        <ng-container *ngIf='session.startDate < todayDate; else oldsession;'>
                            <div class="d-inline" *ngFor="let application of sessionsApplications">
                                <div class="d-inline"  *ngIf="application.key == session.id">
                                    <div *ngIf="application.value != session.capacity; else oldsession;">
                                        <div class="d-inline date">
                                            <svg style="margin-right: 5px;" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar-month" fill="#3366ff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M2.56 11.332L3.1 9.73h1.984l.54 1.602h.718L4.444 6h-.696L1.85 11.332h.71zm1.544-4.527L4.9 9.18H3.284l.8-2.375h.02zm5.746.422h-.676V9.77c0 .652-.414 1.023-1.004 1.023-.539 0-.98-.246-.98-1.012V7.227h-.676v2.746c0 .941.606 1.425 1.453 1.425.656 0 1.043-.28 1.188-.605h.027v.539h.668V7.227zm2.258 5.046c-.563 0-.91-.304-.985-.636h-.687c.094.683.625 1.199 1.668 1.199.93 0 1.746-.527 1.746-1.578V7.227h-.649v.578h-.019c-.191-.348-.637-.64-1.195-.64-.965 0-1.64.679-1.64 1.886v.34c0 1.23.683 1.902 1.64 1.902.558 0 1.008-.293 1.172-.648h.02v.605c0 .645-.423 1.023-1.071 1.023zm.008-4.53c.648 0 1.062.527 1.062 1.359v.253c0 .848-.39 1.364-1.062 1.364-.692 0-1.098-.512-1.098-1.364v-.253c0-.868.406-1.36 1.098-1.36z"/>
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1zm1-3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v11a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm9 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            {{session.startDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
                                            <svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-right-short" fill="#3366ff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.146 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.793 8 8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            {{session.endDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="session.capacity != 0" style="margin-left: 10px;" class="d-inline capacity">
                                            <svg style="margin-right: 5px;" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-lines-fill" fill="#3366ff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm7 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-2-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm2 9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                            <div class="d-inline" *ngFor="let application of sessionsApplications">
                                                <div class="d-inline"  *ngIf="application.key == session.id">
                                                    {{application.value}} / {{session.capacity}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-inline float-right" *ngIf="user.id != courseOwner.id">
                                            <button nbButton status="primary">Join</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-inline float-right" style="margin-left: 10px;" (click)='edit_session_model(session.id)'  *ngIf="user.id == courseOwner.id">
                                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil" fill="#3366ff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l2 2a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.414l-9 9a1 1 0 0 1-.39.242l-3 1a1 1 0 0 1-1.266-1.265l1-3a1 1 0 0 1 .242-.391l9-9zM12 2l2 2-9 9-3 1 1-3 9-9z"/>
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.146 6.354l-2.5-2.5.708-.708 2.5 2.5-.707.708zM3 10v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H4v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H5v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H6v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H3z"/>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="d-inline float-right" *ngIf="user.id == courseOwner.id">
                                            <a [routerLink]="['/pages/session', session.id]"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-sliders" fill="#3366ff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM11.5 5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3zM7 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM4.5 10a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3zm9.5 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM11.5 15a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3z"/>
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.5 4H0V3h9.5v1zM16 4h-2.5V3H16v1zM9.5 14H0v-1h9.5v1zm6.5 0h-2.5v-1H16v1zM6.5 9H16V8H6.5v1zM0 9h2.5V8H0v1z"/>
                                            </svg></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container> 
                        <ng-template #oldsession >
                            <div class="d-inline date">
                                <svg style="margin-right: 5px;" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar-month" fill="#333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M2.56 11.332L3.1 9.73h1.984l.54 1.602h.718L4.444 6h-.696L1.85 11.332h.71zm1.544-4.527L4.9 9.18H3.284l.8-2.375h.02zm5.746.422h-.676V9.77c0 .652-.414 1.023-1.004 1.023-.539 0-.98-.246-.98-1.012V7.227h-.676v2.746c0 .941.606 1.425 1.453 1.425.656 0 1.043-.28 1.188-.605h.027v.539h.668V7.227zm2.258 5.046c-.563 0-.91-.304-.985-.636h-.687c.094.683.625 1.199 1.668 1.199.93 0 1.746-.527 1.746-1.578V7.227h-.649v.578h-.019c-.191-.348-.637-.64-1.195-.64-.965 0-1.64.679-1.64 1.886v.34c0 1.23.683 1.902 1.64 1.902.558 0 1.008-.293 1.172-.648h.02v.605c0 .645-.423 1.023-1.071 1.023zm.008-4.53c.648 0 1.062.527 1.062 1.359v.253c0 .848-.39 1.364-1.062 1.364-.692 0-1.098-.512-1.098-1.364v-.253c0-.868.406-1.36 1.098-1.36z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1zm1-3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v11a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm9 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                                </svg>
                                {{session.startDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
                                <svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-right-short" fill="#333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.146 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.793 8 8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z"/>
                                </svg>
                                {{session.endDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="session.capacity != 0" style="margin-left: 10px;" class="d-inline capacity">
                                <svg style="margin-right: 5px;" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-lines-fill" fill="#333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm7 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-2-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm2 9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                                </svg>
                                <div class="d-inline" *ngFor="let application of sessionsApplications">
                                    <div class="d-inline"  *ngIf="application.key == session.id">
                                        {{application.value}} / {{session.capacity}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline float-right" *ngIf="user.id != courseOwner.id">
                                <button nbButton disabled status="primary">Join</button>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="d-inline float-right" *ngIf="user.id == courseOwner.id">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-sliders" fill="#333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM11.5 5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3zM7 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM4.5 10a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3zm9.5 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0zM11.5 15a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.5 4H0V3h9.5v1zM16 4h-2.5V3H16v1zM9.5 14H0v-1h9.5v1zm6.5 0h-2.5v-1H16v1zM6.5 9H16V8H6.5v1zM0 9h2.5V8H0v1z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </ng-template>
                    </nb-card-body>
                </nb-card>
            </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #nosession>
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
                    <img width="55%" src="assets/images/empty-session.png">
                    <p class="mt-2">This course has no session!</p>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
```

I have checked the console, and it was always empty with no errors, the data is present in the database and the API is always alive.

**EDIT: ** After applying the solution proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627017/6742748), the content starts to appear more than before but still having the same problem but it is less frequent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be due to your 'tasks' variable that you use in your .next is an array, which is an object is js and passed by ref. technically, it would be .nexting the same item, and that causes the subject to not trigger for it's observers.

try something like: (different ways to pass a new object from an existing array)

```
this.taskSubject$.next(new Array(this.tasks))
this.taskSubject$.next([...this.tasks])
this.taskSubject$.next(this.tasks.slice(0))
```

:

```
 this.taskService.getByCourseId(this.course.id).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.tasks = data;
                    this.taskssubject$.next(this.tasks); <<< ----- this.tasks is an array
                }
            );
```

Comment: now it is usually showing the data, but still some small error rate.

Comment: Now it's a matter of tracking down whether the .next() logic gets triggered each time it should, and further debugging from there. console.log() statements and debugger; in your component file will hopefully lead you to the answers. (see 'the debugger keyword' here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you show `nosession` in depend on `sessions.length > 0; else nosession`. Your `sessions` parameter is changed internally from class and Change detector doesn't process it. Make `sessions` observable or use direct Change detector control.

Comment: but even if I waited nothing changes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read your code fully. See my edited answer.